# Is there a way to select/edit all ends of curves in blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, bezier-curves, hair

Basically, I want to take all the tips of curves I've made (through converting hair into mesh then mesh into curves and then applying a bezel to them from a circle curve)  either select them all to size them down to give them a tapered locks of hair look- or I want to somehow apply tapered tips to them from another object in the same way that you can apply a bezel to them.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to object-link to a path and adjust the taper by manipulating that path in edit mode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).